# Running Scrapy with Flask - Unhandled error in EventualResult

Tags: python, flask, scrapy, twisted, twisted.internet

I have a scrapy project that works fine and returns resutls i want.
The spider code is:

```
class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example'
    myBaseUrl = ''
    start_urls = []
    def __init__(self, symbol_url='', **kwargs): 
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.myBaseUrl = symbol_url
        self.start_urls.append(self.myBaseUrl)

    custom_settings = {'FEED_URI': 'output/output.json', 'CLOSESPIDER_TIMEOUT' : 50} 

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse, args={'wait': 5})


    def parse(self, response):
    
        tbody = response.css('tbody.scrollContent')
        row = tbody.css('tr.table__row.ng-scope')
        col = row.css('td')
        links = col.css('a.letter-title.ng-binding.ng-scope::attr(href)')
        for link in links:
        yield response.follow("https://www.example.ir"+link.get(), callback=self.parse_page)


    def parse_page(self, response):

        page = bs(response.text, 'html.parser')
        name = page.find('head', id='Head1').text.strip().split('(')[-1]
        name = name.replace(')', '').strip()
        try:
            tables = page.find_all('tr', class_="ComputationalRow")
            table_head = page.find('table', {'id':'exampleID'})
            date = table_head.findAll('th')[-1].text.split(' ')[3]
            yield MyItem(name=name, date=date)
        except:
            pass
```

And here is my Flask code to run the spider:

```
import crochet
crochet.setup()
from flask import Flask , render_template, jsonify, request, redirect, url_for
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.signalmanager import dispatcher
import time
import os
from EScrapy.example.spiders.example import ExampleSpider

app = Flask(__name__)

output_data = []
crawl_runner = CrawlerRunner()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def submit():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        s = request.form['symbol'] 
        global baseURL
        baseURL = f'https://example.ir/ReportList.aspx?search&Symbol={s}'
        if os.path.exists("output/output.json"): 
            os.remove("output/output.json")
        return redirect(url_for('scrape'))

@app.route("/scrape")
def scrape():
    scrape_with_crochet(baseURL=baseURL)
    time.sleep(20)
    return jsonify(output_data)

@crochet.run_in_reactor
@crochet.wait_for(timeout=10)
def scrape_with_crochet(baseURL):
    dispatcher.connect(_crawler_result, signal=signals.item_scraped)
    eventual = crawl_runner.crawl(ExampleSpider, symbol_url = baseURL)
    return eventual

def _crawler_result(item, response, spider):
    output_data.append(dict(item))


if __name__== "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My spider works properly alone when put the link in `start_urls` and delete `__init__` method. It returns json file but when I want to run the code from flask application i saw this errors in my flask debug mode in commandline and Flask returns empty list:

```
Unhandled error in EventualResult
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "[..]/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 662, in callback
self._startRunCallbacks(result)
   File "[..]/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 764, in _startRunCallbacks
self._runCallbacks()
  File "[..]/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 858, in _runCallbacks
   current.result = callback(  # type: ignore[misc]
  File "[..]/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1751, in gotResult
current_context.run(_inlineCallbacks, r, gen, status)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "[..]/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1661, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = current_context.run(gen.send, result)
builtins.StopIteration:
```

I need to this project as my hiring task and really stuck in this problem. Have you any idea to how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from using baseURL as global. In Flask there are a [request](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/reqcontext/) and [app context](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/appcontext/) concepts. The scraping process can take time, so you can't run it within the request context due to timeout. So it's better to use a task manager for it. Like Redis or Celery. Just google "flask redis scrapy" or read [this chapter](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xxii-background-jobs) from the Brilliant Flask tutorial by Miguel Grinberg

Comment: I found out it's because of `SplashRequest` in my spider. Flask works with other spiders that don't use splash. But i don't have any idea why it's behves same and how to fix this.

Comment: I get a similar error executing a spider in Jupyter Notebook (scarapy 2.7.0)